# Nutch and solr indexing blacklist domain

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

I am using nutch 1.9 and solr 4.10 .I want to avoid domain  www.aaa.com gettign index in nutch and solr

In the  nutch configurations 
conf/domainblacklist-urlfilter.txt I have added "www.aaa.com". in the conf/domain-urlfilter.txt I have added "www.bbb.com"
In the regex-urlfilter.txt I have added

+^http://www.bbb.com
-^http://www.aaa.com

But notice  that it still in solr that the domain with  www.aaa.com is getting index.

Could some one provide inputs as how this can be resolved

Answer (score 0):

To avoid to indexing an url, the most simple solution it's to avoid to crawl this url.

- Add this line to regex-urlfilter.txt:

  ```
  -^(http|https)://.*aaa.*$
  ```
- Add this configuration in your nutch-site.xml (i added some extra plugins):

  ```
  <property>
  <name>plugin.includes</name>
  <value>protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-regex|parse-(text|tika|js)|index-(basic|anchor)|query-(basic|site|url)|response-(json|xml)|summary-basic|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)|indexer-solr
  </value>
  </property>
  ```
- Compile in your $NUTCH_HOME:

  ```
  ant runtime
  ```
- If it's not enough, this is because in your database or files, you have some bad urls. So delete all your database (Hbase/Cassandra for nutch 2 and segments files for nutch 1). After that, retry to crawl and it would be good. :)